# Need help passing a data attribute into a form redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, expressionengine

hoping someone can help me with this.

Firstly to summarize, I have a list of items that each have a 'Book Now' button, once the book now button is clicked then they redirect to their respective pages. What I have added in between this is a modal popup.

So when a new user comes to the site, clicks a book now button on one of the list items, the modal will appear. They then type in some details and submit submit the form

Then, ideally, they would be redirected to the appropriate page. The items with the Book Now button are generated through a loop of Expression Engine entries so the links are never hard coded.

My problem is that the code for the modal form itself cannot be inside the loop of entries and so therefore cannot read which URL to link to once it's submitted so I figured I would have to use JavaScript to solve this.

My thinking was to add a data-link attribute to the Book Now button, then in JavaScript tell the form that once submitted it should redirect to the value inside the data-link attribute of the link that was clicked.

I hope this makes sense to someone. Is this possible? Can someone perhaps offer some advice

Thanks

Edit: added code

```
<a class="booking-tracker" href="#" data-link="{base_url}ticket/{url_title}">Book now</a>


<div class="modal-wrapper" id="wrapper-modal" style="display:none;">
<form>
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="redirectvalue here pulled from initial link data-attribute">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div><!--modal-->


<script>         
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.booking-tracker').on("click", function (event) {
    if(f24('autoId') == '' && f24('personId') == '') {      
document.getElementById('wrapper-modal').style.display='block';
    } 
    else {
window.location = $(this).data('link');
}
});
});
</script>
```

So this script above will trigger the modal if the user is new to the site and hasn't previously recorded their details, otherwise it will link to the default URL of that link, it's just the form redirect that I'm struggling with

Comment: You can create the modal, set it `hidden`, show it on the click of the button thanks to JQuery ( `.click()` ), and handle it like a standardized html

Comment: Getting the modal to show isn't the problem, it's the form contained in the modal. It's getting that to redirect to the right place according to which link was clicked to trigger the modal

Comment: Your idea of writing the URL somewhere you can later retrieve it seems sound enough, have you tried to write it? What issues are you running into? If you have any code to share, I'm sure we can help you out.

Comment: Have added code in edit

Answer (score 0):

Use data on the button to generate a unique url. When the button is clicked get this data and add it to the hidden element of your form. I did up a little example. Hope it helps!

```js
var redirect_link = 'www.thisisyourredirectlink.com/';
$('.click-for-modal').on('click' , function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); // Used anchor tags so prevent default
 var redirect_id = $(this).attr('id');
 var new_redirect = redirect_link + redirect_id;
 $('#redirect').removeAttr('value'); //remove if it has been set previously
 $('#redirect').attr('value' , new_redirect); // Add current id
 console.log(new_redirect);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="click-for-modal" id="1" href="">Button</a>
<a class="click-for-modal" id="2" href="">Button</a>
<a class="click-for-modal" id="3" href="">Button</a>
<a class="click-for-modal" id="4" href="">Button</a>
<a class="click-for-modal" id="5" href="">Button</a>
<a class="click-for-modal" id="6" href="">Button</a>

<div class="modal-wrapper" id="wrapper-modal" style="">
<form>
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
  <input id="redirect" type="hidden" name="redirect" value="redirectvalue here pulled from initial link data-attribute">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div><!--modal-->
```